# A solution without using Gram schmidt required.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, inner-products, orthonormal

The question is given below:

> [image]

I found a solution online using Gram Schmidt procedure but I need a solution without it, could anyone help me in this, please?

**EDIT:**

I was given a hint that I can show that there is a dual basis and that the inner product establishes an isomorphism $\delta$ between the space and its dual and to let $w_{j} = \delta^{-1} (v_{j}^*)$ where $v_{j}^*$ are the dual basis of $v_{j}$ and that $<v_{i}, w_{j}> \delta_{w_{j} (v_{i})}$ but still I do not understand the intuition of the hint. could anyone explain for me what is this hint doing?

Comment: This boils down to solving an appropriate system of linear equations.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro how ? could you provide more details please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us focus on $w_1$ first.
Since $\langle v_i, w_1 \rangle = 0$ for $i = 2, \ldots, n$, we know $w_1$ must lie in the orthogonal complement of $\text{span}\{v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$. This orthogonal complement is nontrivial (since $\text{span}\{v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ has dimension $<n$), so there exists some vector $u$ in it. We must have $\langle u, v_1 \rangle \ne 0$, else $v_1$ lies in $\text{span}\{v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ which contradicts the fact that $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$ is a basis. Thus, we can choose $w_1 := \frac{1}{\langle u, v_1 \rangle} u$ to obtain $\langle w_1, v_1 \rangle = 1$.

The other $w_2, \ldots, w_n$ can be determined similarly.

Comment: And what about proving that it is a basis?

Answer (score 3):

Write 
$$
w_j= \sum_k x_{jk} v_k.$$ 
Then the condition $\langle v_i, w_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ is equivalent to 
$$
\sum_k x_{jk} \langle v_i, v_k\rangle = \delta_{ij}, $$ 
which is the system of $n^2$ linear equations given in matrix form as $AX=I$, where 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} \langle v_i, v_j\rangle\end{bmatrix}, \quad X=\begin{bmatrix} x_{ij}\end{bmatrix}, $$ 
and $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

> **Therefore**, what really needs to be done is proving that $A$ is invertible.

To do that, try exploring the concept of *Gramian matrix*, for example on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

Comment: what about the hint I edited in the question ? do you have any idea about the intuition behind that hint?

Comment: and how can I prove that these $w_{j}$ 's form a basis?

Comment: That hint is too abstract for me, I generally prefer to try and reduce this kind of problems to something algorithmical, whenever possible. Concerning the proof that $w_j$ form a basis, this is the same as requiring that $X$ is invertible. If $A$ is invertible, then $X=A^{-1}$ is invertible as well. So, again, it reduces to the proof that $A$ is invertible. The standard way to do it is observing that $A$ is positive definite (this requires that the scalar field be the reals or the complex numbers).